# why is this more efficient?

Tags: javascript, performance

why 'code01' is more efficient than 'code02'? it seems like both codes are still getting the remainder after all the operation finished.

```
// code01

function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent === 0) return 1;

  const half = parseInt(exponent / 2);
  const temp = power(base, half);
  const result = (temp * temp) % 94906249;

  if (exponent % 2 === 1) return (base * result) % 94906249;
  else return result;
}
```

```
//code02

function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent === 0) return 1;

  return base * power(base, exponent - 1) % 94906249;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one uses `exponent / 2` in the recursion, the second one `exponent - 1`.

Repeated division gives you logarithmic runtime, repeated subtraction gives you linear runtime.

Compare:

| division | subtraction |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 8 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 5 |
| . | 4 |
|  | 3 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 1 |
|  | . |

Division with a factor of 2 means 4 steps for input 8, 5 steps for input 16, 11 steps for input ~1000. Subtraction of 1 means 1000 steps for input 1000. 11 is a lot less than 1000.